# How to save an object unknown at compile time to a variable by pattern matching in Rust?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

**TLDR;** *How do you make Rust's pattern matching behave dynamically like Python 3?*

I'm quite new to Rust, and I struggle with a certain concept / code snippet.
I'm trying to assign an object that is unknown at compile time to a variable using pattern matching. The different objects share a common trait, which contains the only methods I want to use on this object.

```
trait DoAction { fn action(&self); }

struct ObjectA { ... }
impl DoAction for ObjectA { fn action(&self) { ... } }

struct ObjectB { ... }
impl DoAction for ObjectB { fn action(&self) { ... } }

// This does not work
let object = match condition {
    true => ObjectA { ... },
    false => ObjectB { ... },
};

// I want to call this
object.action();
```

Working Python 3 example for comparison (what I want to achieve).

```
object = ObjectA(...) if true else ObjectB(...)
```

All help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically dispatch them,remember that for that you need to **box** your types:

```rust
let object: Box<dyn DoAction> = match condition {
    true => Box::new(ObjectA { ... }),
    false => Box::neww(ObjectB { ... }),
};
```

or

```rust
let object = match condition {
    true => Box::new(ObjectA { ... }) as Box<dyn DoAction>,
    false => Box::neww(ObjectB { ... }) as Box<dyn DoAction>,
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the top one, and it worked like a charm. Should I use Box whenever I want to dynamically allocate memory?

Comment: It depends if you want to keep the object as the trait itself or not. In this case I would say you would need Box, because you need something to actually own the underlaying data.

Answer (score 0):

Besides @Netwave's variants, there's a possibility to cast the objects to `&dyn DoAction`, without dealing with heap allocation of `Box`

```
trait DoAction { fn action(&self); }

struct ObjectA {}
impl DoAction for ObjectA { 
    fn action(&self) { println!("A"); } 
}

struct ObjectB { }
impl DoAction for ObjectB { 
    fn action(&self) { println!("B"); } 
}
fn main() {
    let condition = true;
    let object = match condition {
        true => &ObjectA{} as &dyn DoAction,
        false => &ObjectB{} as &dyn DoAction,
    };
    
    object.action(); // prints "A"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it more common to use this pattern than to use `Box`? I would think using `Box` might be simpler, but this approach is more efficient. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: That depends how long you want your objects to live, if it's just in the current function and then you throw them away, then my variant is more efficient (yet a bit ugly, and not common)

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this thing still persists in Rust, but there used to be a flaw of Rust's `Box` that it doesn't create objects in the heap in place. Meaning that in `Box::new(ObjectA{...})`, the `ObjectA` is first created on stack, then `Box` allocates heap memory of same size, and the content of `ObjectA` is copied byte-by-byte into heap location. So if your object is very heavy on stack (which is unlikely), it also may be a problem when using `Box`.

Comment: This method doesn't work with types that can't be const-promoted ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dd9f8f247a77ec5ea3d5301b9b4ba49f)) *"temorary value dropped while borrowed"*. A similar trick can be done with conditionally-initialized local variables ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a16bb4e983d1425d09fe6401890dc7be)) but I don't tend to use this trick personally.